Can I see on debug / breakpoint / tracepoint on how much times a method run using Visual Studio 2022
I have a custom attribute class. The custom attribute runs on every request. Since my requests are async. I want to know how many times my method on custom attribute runs.
Is there a way to count the execution of method or create a trace point on Visual Studio 2022?
I tried to look the breakpoint settings. On actions, I put {hitcount} as a message output window. But did not work.

I don’t think this is possible. Can’t you add a counter to the attribute code?

Thanks! @stuartd I also used the example of Dou Xu-MSFT, I created a temporary variable just to see the total hitcount.

As @stuartd said, if you want to  count the execution of method or create a trace point, you can add a counter to your code. For detailed steps, please check the following:
1.Create a static variable outside the method. Increment it every time method gets called.
 public static int counter = 0;
 public void myMethod()
 {
     Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
 }

2.Set tracepoints in your method. Enter the message {counter} into the Show a message in the Output Window text box.

Test result

Doc Referred:
Set tracepoints in source code

This is working for quick debugging. thank you!
